# What the tag "& > *" means? Used in useStyles functions

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, material-ui

I'm using React with Material-UI for a while and I noticed that in some examples, when they are using the `useStyle` they create a class called root and then they use this tag `& > *`. I tried searching what this means but it's hard to search for it.

[Here](https://material-ui.com/api/paper/) follows an example from their documentation:

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    '& > *': {
      margin: theme.spacing(1),
      width: theme.spacing(16),
      height: theme.spacing(16),
    },
  },
}));

export default function SimplePaper() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Paper />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This may help - https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In sass the `&` allows you to 'chain' css selectors, in regular css `>` means direct descendant so if you were only trying to target the top level `div`s inside something you could use `>` e.g.

```
// css
article > div {
  font-size: 40px;
}

// html
<article>
  <div>
    Heading // this is 40px because this div is a direct descendant of article
    <div>
      Some content // this is unaffected because it's two levels away from article
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    Another heading // this is also 40px big, because it is only one level deep in article
  </div>
</article>
```

and the `*` selector means everything

So in the example you gave `.root & > *` or just `.root > *` means that every direct descendant element of the class root will have those styles applied to it, but the elements inside those will not.